# SSRS Currency Format IIF Expression

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, expression, ssrs-expression

I'm trying to format the text box properties based off an expression, I have a field 'currencyID' and I'm trying to get it to change from £ to € if the value doesn't equal 1. So far I've got this but I am terrible at SSRS Expressions...

```
=IIF(Fields!currencyID.Value = 1, '£'#,0.00;('£'#,0.00), '€'#,0.00;('€'#,0.00))
```

This is to save having a report for UK clients and a separate report for Irish clients.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You've not actually said what is now working and what issues you are facing...?  That said, it looks like you need to wrap your format strings in double quotes?

Comment: Thank you that sorted it! the correct expression was 

=IIF(Fields!currencyID.Value = 1, "'£'#,0.00;('£'#,0.00)", "'€'#,0.00;('€'#,0.00)")

The issue was I was getting an expression error but it didn't make clear what the issue was, obviously now I know it was lack of double quotes.